# Why is the template trying to instanciate with 'int&' instead of 'int'?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a simple function that will get me a number from user input within a range.

When instanciating this function i explicitly tell it i want it instanciated with `int` but still i get the error:

```
thermo.cpp:105:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘getInput(int&)’
```

Why is is trying to find a function that takes `int&` as argument?

```
template<class T, T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min, T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max>
T getInput(T default_value = T()){
  std::string input;
  T myNumber = T(); //default inits
  while(true){
    getline(cin, input);

    if(input.length() == 0){
      return default_value;
    }

    // This code converts from string to number safely.
    stringstream myStream(input);
    if (myStream >> myNumber){
      if(myNumber > max || myNumber < min){
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "Input out of bounds. Received " << myNumber << " expected between " << min << " and " << max << ".";
        throw invalid_argument(ss.str());
      }
      return myNumber;
    }

    cout << "Invalid number, please try again" << endl;
  }
}

void get(const std::string& prompt, int& param){
  cout << prompt << " [" << param << "]:";
  param = getInput<int,0>(param); // i specifically tell it i want 'int', why am i getting 'int&'?
}
```

**Update**

If i try CharlesB suggestion:

```
void get(const std::string& prompt, int& param){
  cout << prompt << " [" << param << "]:";
  param = getInput<int,0>(int(param));
}
```

i get

> thermo.cpp:105:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘getInput(int)’

Forgot:

> g++ 4.5.3 under cygwin

Command line:

> $ g++ thermo.cpp -o thermo.exe -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x

**Update 2**

if i call it like this

```
void get(const std::string& prompt, int& param){
  cout << prompt << " [" << param << "]:";
  param = getInput<int,0,15>(int(param)); // fully parameterized
}
```

it works... but i'd rather not specify an upper bound (not even `numeric_limits`) on each call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use templates for `min` and `max`:

```
template<class T>
T getInput(T default_value = T(), T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
```

There is no reason to use templates for those arguments(besides the fact that it does not work).

**Edit**: You can't use those arguments as template values since `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is a function, its value is known on runtime, and template value arguments have to be bound to a value at compile time. This is valid:

```
template<class T, T min = 0, T max = 5>
T getInput(T default_value);
```

Since 0 and 5 are known during compilation.

Comment: Yes, that also came to me. But then the other question is: Why do the `min` and `max` brake the lookup of the function...

Comment: Yep, that's it... Who the hell decided to make those functions and not constants...

Comment: @RedX: That's been fixed in C++11, by making the functions `constexpr`. However, you'll need g++ 4.6 or later for that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is **the** issue, but I can't imagine it's helping.  This line:

```
template<class T, T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min, T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max>
```

...is using min/max as values, [when they're really functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/).  Maybe that's confusing the template parameters?

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. I mean, it is a problem, but doing that doesn't make it work.

Comment: @fontanini: Doing that does make it work with a reasonably C++11-compliant compiler, although that won't help if the OP is stuck with his version of g++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Nice, didn't know about those functions becoming constexpr in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

The error code does not mean what you think. The error code is a shorthand for:

*no matching function call to `getInput` that takes an `int` modifiable lvalue expression as the single argument*

Where *`int` modifiable lvalue expression* is the type of the expression that you are using to make the **call** in this case `param`. Now the problem is that output of error codes in this format is that it is very verbose and it would become very hard to read with just two or three arguments of non trivial types, so the compiler condenses the error report and tells you:

*no matching function call to `getInput(int&)`*, note that here `int&` is not the type of the function that will be called, as the compiler was unable to find such a function, but rather it is the type of the argument that is being used in the call.

If you perform the change that CharlesB suggests, then you will get a different error message saying that it cannot find `getInput(int)`. The difference here is that `int(param)` creates a temporary (*rvalue expression*), so the error now reflects it. The need for a different error code comes from the fact that if you had a `getInput(int&)` function, in this second case, that overload cannot be used.

On the reason why you are getting that error code the basic problem is that `std::numeric_limits<T>::max` is not of type `T`. Your problem is the very base of SFINAE: You have defined a template that takes as second and third arguments `T`, and that `T` should be initialized with `std::numeric_limits<T>::min` (and `max`). Now when the compiler tries to determine the function to call, it will find that template, use `T` for `int` (you provided the exact type), `0` for the min and will then try to infer the last argument. At this point it will try to get a `T` value (last template argument) through the default template argument by substituting the known template arguments in: `std::numeric_limits<T>::max`. The problem is that `std::numeric_limits<int>::max` is not an `int`, but rather a static member function, so the types don't match, yielding a substitution failure. The language determins that *substitution failure is not an error* (**SFINAE**) and it only means that this template will be removed from the list of candidates for the function call. Because there is no other matching overload, the compiler gives up and tells you that it could not find a matching function for the call.

In C++11 you can use `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`, as the function is marked as a `const_expr` and can thus be *called* to obtain a constant expression of type `T` that can be used as the template argument, but if you are working with a C++03 compiler, you will need to work around the problem in a different way, like moving the `min` and `max` to default arguments to a function, or providing different overloads that take values from the user or will call a function (default to `std::numeric_limist<T>::max` if the argument is not present, but this latter option is more cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Template functions are instanciated with argument type, and `param` is a `int&`.

Rather do

```
 param = getInput(int(param));
```

Also min and max can't be template arguments, a template argument is class, a typename or a POD.

Comment: If i do that i get: `thermo.cpp:105:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘getInput(int)’`. This is somehow baffling...

Comment: Also min and max can't be template arguments, a template argument is class or a typename, not a value.

Comment: Templates arguments can actually be values. `template<int k> void foo();` that is perfectly valid.

Comment: That may still be a part of the issue, you're using T as the type of template argument where C++ only guarantees that integer types (ie, int) will work. Does it help if you replace them with ints?

Comment: But i thought i am able to do: `template<int N>void func(int a = N){}` so why can't a have min or max as my template arguments?

Comment: @dascandy currently i am only trying with `int`. This function currently only takes PODs that are not floats.